# Slow loading app in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, environment, performance

I have an app based on Rails 3 (version `Rails 3.1.2`) and `ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]`. The loading of the app is so slow, right now, when I tried it, I was waiting **23 seconds**, than the index page was loaded. It is the same as on the Heroku as on the localhost.

I found similar topics here on SO, but unfortunately I didn't find there a solution that would solve my problem. Somewhere on a blog I read, that this problem could be caused, because the page no one long time visited.

But again - I nowhere find a solution for this... so I would like to ask you, if anyone have already this problem in the past and have a solution, I would very grateful for this.

Many thanks.

**EDIT** - Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'
gem "rvm", "~> 1.9.2"
gem 'authlogic'
gem "rake", "0.8.7"
gem 'json'
gem "declarative_authorization", "~> 0.5.3"
gem "ancestry", "~> 1.2.4"
gem "taps", "~> 0.3.23"
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.4.5"
gem 'aws-s3'
gem "awesome_print", "~> 1.0.1"
gem 'actionmailer'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5.rc.2'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'therubyracer-heroku', '0.8.1.pre3'
  gem 'pg'
end



gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'
```

**EDIT2** - versions of used gems:

```
Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using multi_json (1.0.4) 
Using activesupport (3.1.2) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using activemodel (3.1.2) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.3.6) 
Using rack-cache (1.1) 
Using rack-mount (0.8.3) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.2) 
Using actionpack (3.1.2) 
Using mime-types (1.17.2) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.3.0) 
Using actionmailer (3.1.2) 
Using arel (2.2.1) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.31) 
Using activerecord (3.1.2) 
Using activeresource (3.1.2) 
Using ancestry (1.2.4) 
Using authlogic (3.1.0) 
Using awesome_print (1.0.2) 
Using xml-simple (1.1.1) 
Using aws-s3 (0.6.2) 
Using bundler (1.0.21) 
Using cocaine (0.2.1) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.2.0) 
Installing execjs (1.3.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.6.5) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.1.2) 
Using coffee-rails (3.1.1) 
Installing declarative_authorization (0.5.5) 
Using jquery-rails (1.0.19) 
Using mysql2 (0.3.11) 
Using paperclip (2.4.5) 
Using rails (3.1.2) 
Using rails3-jquery-autocomplete (1.0.5) 
Using rest-client (1.6.7) 
Using rvm (1.9.2) 
Using sass (3.1.12) 
Using sass-rails (3.1.5) 
Using sequel (3.20.0) 
Using sinatra (1.0) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.5) 
Using sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3) 
Using taps (0.3.23) 
Using uglifier (1.2.2) 
Using wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.9.5.3)
```

Comment: like a some kind of black parade

Comment: are you testing the app in development mode or production mode?

Comment: as I said above - I tried it in the development mode on localhost. And also in the production mode on the Heroku - and the result is in the both cases the same.

Comment: @fkreusch sure, look at the updated post, please.

Comment: The first step is to debug correctly. Is this just the first request (or every time)? Is this server time, or browser time? Look in the logs... `Completed 200 OK in XXXXms (Views: YYYYms | ActiveRecord: ZZZZms)`, what are the X, Y, and Z.

Comment: I thought your initial loading was slow, but now I see it's your index page. Your Gemfile is fine tough (any special reason to include rvm in there?). Other things you can do is to check the log as the previous comment told you. What kind of logic do you have in your controller action? Anything in ApplicationController?

Comment: Here are the values: When I run my app on localhost, I'll get this values: `Completed 200 OK in 2875ms (Views: 1371.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1480.7ms)` - but the page is displayed in 5-6 seconds, the generated values are a bit low I think. [Here](https://gist.github.com/1652483) is the link to the log by Heroku - on the line #35 is the start.

Comment: @fkreusch in `ApplicationController` are actions for `Authlogic`, nothing more.

Comment: Can you paste a localhost log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I discovered, the problem is in dynos on Heroku. If you use Heroku as free, you have assigned 1 dyno. When nobody visit your page during a time (eg. 1 hour), so this dyno is idle -> that's the reason of long time of loading the page.

If you buy the second dyno ($35 per month), so the dyno will be never idled and we will never meet the "slow loading" situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because You are running with old versions of gems maybe. Please update all gems to it's newest versions and try again. It helps me when I had similiar problem.

Comment: look at the updated original post, please. I ran `bundle upadte` and these are versions of my gems.